# No irreducible element in a UFD can be a square.

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> We wish to prove that no irreducible element in a Unique Factorization Domain $D$ can be written as a square of some element in its field of fraction $F$.

Take $x$ in $D$, and we go for a contradiction. Write $x=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{2}$. My goal is, of course, to contradict the irreducibility of $x$. But, I'm having some trouble.

Comment: Think what happens over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then generalize

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't seen this question before, but I thought immediately of the proof that the square root of 2 is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume $a$ and $b$ coprime. We get $xb^2 = a^2$. Now a prime factor of $a$ must divide $x$ 2 times, thus $x$ is not irriducible. Contradiction.

Comment: sorry, I edit! :) I suspected that the other ordering sounded better, but I hoped it didn't matter!

Answer (score 0):

As hinted, the proof is virtually the same as proving the square root of 2 is irrational. We can assume by dividing out a power of $x$ that at least one of $a,b$ is not divisible by $x$. Then since
$$b^2x=a^2$$
and we are in a UFD, $x\mid a$ (because $x$ is prime). Write $a=cx$ where $c$ is in our base ring. Then
$$b^2x=c^2x^2$$
so
$$b^2=c^2x$$
and hence $x$ divides $b$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ In $\,a^2 = x b^2$ the prime $x$ occurs to even power on LHS but odd power on RHS, contradiction. Note the the proof uses the existence *and* uniqueness of prime factorizations.

**Remark** $\ $ More generally the classical proof of the Rational Root Test easily generalizes to UFDs. In particular it implies that if $\,z^2 - d\, $ has a rational root (i.e. in the quotient field of $D)$ then that root is integral, i.e. in $D,\,$ just like the classical case $D = \Bbb Z$